# What's the current state of the Kult rights?

Tags: kult

I am pretty sure Kult's not currently in print from anyone, and I'm reasonably familiar with the US publication history. However, I haven't been able to find any information on plans, attempts, or dreams regarding republication in English or anywhere else. It may be one of those legions of 1990s games that doesn't have a fan base to sustain a reprint, but I'd be interested if anyone was trying.

Comment: The accepted answer *is not accurate*. Could you accept the other one?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because what is “current” is a moving target as time passes: ownership and especially licensing of an IP can and does frequently change.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

It seems to be owned by Paradox Entertainment, but they seem more concerned with licensing, so my guess is that you'll see a *Kult* film or TV series before you see a new edition of the rpg.

There appears to be an active fan community at [The Last Cycle](http://www.kult-rpg.com/), and they will probably know all the details.

Comment: [This is out of date…](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76285/2100)

Answer (score 17):

In 2015 it was licenced to [Helmgast AB](http://helmgast.se/) who decided to release a new version named [Kult: Divinity Lost](http://kultdivinitylost.com/) (cover photo probably **NSFW**). The project was funded via Kickstarter in early 2016. A Quickstart document was [released in late 2016](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1037361623/kult-divinity-lost-horror-roleplaying-game-rpg/posts/1769595).

According to the Kickstarter page, the text was ready in swedish and the effort was to complete the translation to English. Beta release was available in late December 2017 to pledgers with a later release around mid-2018.

Public release happened in November 2018 and is distributed by [Modiphius](https://www.modiphius.net/collections/kult) (but also available directly through [Helmgast's webstore](http://webshop.helmgast.se/en/kult/) or through [DriveThruRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/browse/pub/4329/Modiphius/subcategory/8425_30667/Kult)). Also, a few [quickplay scenarios](https://kultdivinitylost.com/resources/) have been released (also free in [DTRPG](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/265904/KULT-Free-Quickplay-Scenarios)).